# How do create database dynamically in zend framework2 and also after create dynamically table?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

How do create database dynamically in zend framework2 and also after create dynamically table ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using doctrine orm with zend framework 2. Then you can user doctrine to generate tables from entities (database can be manually created).

See following command

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --force
```

You also have choice to generate sql only

```
vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:update --dump-sql
```

In case of Zend DB, You may need to write your own code to generate schema & then DB.